# Playfair cipher won't print letters into 5x5 table

Tags: python

I am in the beginning stages of my playfair cipher. I am trying to get the key and alphabet to print onto the box. However I am having difficulty and can only print out a 5x5 table with "*".

For those who are not familiar with the playfair cipher the rule is to print a key such as "mathematics" into a 5x5 table along with the rest of the alphabet with each letter only appearing once. I am using a list of lists and iterating over each element of the list. When I think it has stored all the letters back into the list, the result I get is a 5x5 table of "*"'s instead of a 5x5 table of letters. Here is the code I am working with. How can I fix this problem?

```
alphabet = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

#no j

# Initialize a 5 by 5 table of stars
table = []

def print_table():
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
            print(table[row][col],end="")
        print("")

def clear_table():
    for row in range(5):
        table.append([])
        for col in range(5):
            table[row].append("*")

# This was added by
def find_letter(letter):
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if table[row][col] == letter:
                    return row, col
        return -1, -1

def table_has_letter(letter):
    return find_letter(letter)[0] != -1
    # Write code here to search the table for the given letter
    # and return True or False depending on if the letter exists

def table_next_opening():
    return find_letter("*")

def table_insert_letter(letter):
    letter=letter.upper()
    letter= "I" if letter == "J" else letter
    if letter in alphabet and not table_has_letter(letter):
        open_pos= table_next_opening()
        table[open_pos[0]][open_pos[1]] = letter
        ww = open_pos
        return (ww)

def create_table(secret):
    clear_table()
    for letter in secret:
        table_insert_letter(letter)
    for ex_letter in  alphabet:
        table_insert_letter(ex_letter)

create_table("Mathematics")
print_table()

print("")

create_table("Playfair example")
print_table()  # Should match wikipedia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `table_insert_letter` you convert your input letter to an upper case letter and then try to find it in `alphabet`. The `alphabet` strings contains only lower case characters though. If you use an upper case `alphabet` or transform your input letter to lower case (using `str.lower()`) it works.

**Edit:** For your second example to work you also need to take a look at your `clear_table` function. It does not work as expected, as you are not dropping the old table. Try this:

```
def clear_table():
    global table
    table = []
    for row in range(5):
        table.append([])
        for col in range(5):
            table[row].append("*")
```

In my opinion this is also a nice place to write a class, with table as an attribute, so you save yourself the trouble of managing a global variable and can use several ciphers at the same time.